# Calculate The Total Result of The Arithmetic Sequence With Big Number in Less Than 1 Second

Tags: python-3.x

How to Construct a **Python 3** function sum(n) that takes a positive integer n as an input and perform the following computation:

```
sum(n)=5+10+⋯+5(n−1)+5n.
```

The value of n is between 1 and 10^15. The timelimit for the computation is **1 second**. To make your code efficient, try to use the explicit formula (closed form) of sum(n).

**Test:**

```
print(sum(1))
print(sum(2))
print(sum(3))
```

**Result:**

```
5
15
30
```

**What I Have Tried:**

```
def sum(n):
    AK = 0
    n += 1
    for i in range(1,n):
        P = 5 * i
        AK += P
    return AK
```

Unfortunately it takes more than 1 second to finish

Comment: The result is 5 times the sum of 1..n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as Hans Kesting said, the result is 5 times the sum of 1...n and so you can try this simple and easy piece of code. I haven't actually tried it but in practice, it should be less than one second

```
def sum(n):
    return 5 * (n * (n + 1) // 2)
```